# .NET HTTP GET request problem (return state 200 OK instead of 302 Found)

Tags: .net, httpclient, tls1.2

i'm running the following code but received different result than a call made from browser (example chrome).
The .net code gives me 200 (OK) while Chrome 302 with redirect url. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf certVerify

Dim client As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient
Dim requestMessage As New System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
requestMessage.RequestUri = New Uri("https://iampe.agenziaentrate.gov.it/sam/UI/Logout?realm=/agenziaentrate")
requestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Get
requestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"))
requestMessage.Headers.Host = "iampe.agenziaentrate.gov.it"
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua", """ Not A;Brand"";v=""99"", ""Chromium"";v=""96"", ""Google Chrome"";v=""96""")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", """Windows""")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
requestMessage.Headers.UserAgent.Add(New ProductInfoHeaderValue("ScraperBot", "1.0"))
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.9")
Dim Risposta As System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result



Public Function certVerify(se As Object, cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, sslerror As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors)
        Return True
    End Function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9ugo.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-6.0)  is defaulted to enabled. HttpClient is automatically following the redirect and returning the info from the redirected location.

> If AllowAutoRedirect is set to false, all HTTP responses with an HTTP status code from 300 to 399 are returned to the application.

I'm not a VB developer so can't really show you how to do it in VB but there is C# code on the [docs page for HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-6.0) that shows how you can customize behaviour for HttpClient by passing it a instance on HttpClientHandler. You should be able to adapt that to your needs.

**C#**

```
   // Create an HttpClientHandler that doesn't follow redirects
   HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
   handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

   // Create an HttpClient object
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```